# SSL pinning on MobileFirst 6.3 project

Tags: ssl, ibm-mobilefirst

SSL pinning on MobileFirst 6.3 project

Is it possible to implement SSL pinning on MobileFirst 6.3 project ?

Answer (score 1):

Built-in Certificate Pinning is available in MobileFirst 7.1; consider upgrading.

Otherwise you may be able to find 3rd part Cordova plug-ins that provide Certificate Pinning functionality.